# i have an empty arraylist when trying to initialize it with values from enum

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I have a class Card, with fields suit and value from enum files, and I want to initialize  arraylist of Card, card has fields such as suit and value but in the end a have an empty list,seems that problem in initializing with these for loops in deck class, but i dont know how to do it correct with values from enums, i just dont want to add one card after another in list instead to make it with loops, (how to initialize arraylist correct)

```
public enum Suits {
    HEART, DIAMOND, CLUB, SPADE;

}
public enum ValuesOfCards {
SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TENTH,JACK,QUEEN,KING,ACE;

}


public class Card {
public static String mast;
private static int points;
private Suits suit;
private ValuesOfCards vof;


public Card( Suits suit, ValuesOfCards vof) {

    this.suit = suit;
    this.vof = vof;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Card{" +
            "suit=" + suit +
            ", vof=" + vof +
            '}';
}
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Deck {
private ArrayList<Card> deckOfCards;


public Deck() {
    this.deckOfCards = new ArrayList<>();
    initializeDeck();

}

public void initializeDeck(){
    deckOfCards = new ArrayList<>(32);
    for (Card c : deckOfCards){
        for(Suits s : Suits.values()){
            for (ValuesOfCards v : ValuesOfCards.values()){
                deckOfCards.add(new Card(s,v));

            }
        }

    }


}

public ArrayList<Card> getDeckOfCards() {

    return deckOfCards;
}

public ArrayList<Card> shuffleDeckOfCards(){
    ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Deck{" +
            "deckOfCards=" + deckOfCards +
            '}';
}
}
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    deck.initializeDeck();
    System.out.println(  deck.getDeckOfCards());
    deck.shuffleDeckOfCards();
    System.out.println(deck.getDeckOfCards());
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you iterating empty deckOfCards in `for (Card c : deckOfCards)`?

Comment: To add to the above comment, removing that line will fix your problem.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(deckOfCards)` instead of `Collections.shuffle(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
for (Card c : deckOfCards){
```

... and the corresponding closing curly bracket.

Iterating over the empty ArrayList deckOfCards means that the following two for loops will not be executed.